# Applescript temporarily stop user input/detect through mouse and keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, applescript, mojave, mouse

I've looking through apple forums and here looking for a solution. The only solution I could find was to permanently disable the built in Keyboard (which is clearly not a great solution).

Can anyone suggest a solution which can either stop the program if it detects user input or temporarily stop user input for a short amount of time while the script 'keystrokes' something for the user.

Background Info:
I'm trying to create a script that enters an email address into a program automatically. I want to be able to stop the user from interfering with the scripts actions (such as placing the text cursor elsewhere or clicking on something irrelevant). I was able to create this program using Autoit but I am now creating a mac version using AppleScript.

I get the program to input the email through keystrokes.

Comment: Nope.  That would be a security vulnerability if an application or script could shut out the user and start keystroking on the user's behalf.  While keystroking is, of course, possible (though a bad technique in scripting), shutting the user out I do not believe is possible, nor should it be.

Comment: @CJK I know it is bad practice and i'm looking for more like a solution that Autoit provides. In Autoit if the keyboard and mouse is locked then they can be unlocked by pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL. Even if I find a solution that does not have this feature, I would probably program one in anyway (as I don't trust locking myself out anyway). Do you have any idea towards a solution where I can detect user input instead?

Comment: Can you add some more background information about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @nohillside I have added the background information to my question.

Comment: What program are you wanting to enter the email address into?

Comment: @CJK Why is the program important?

Comment: It will determine the options available for achieving your end goal in the best way possible.

Comment: @CJK Keeper as in this program https://keepersecurity.com/